# How do I get the value of clustered record with Weka in Java?

Tags: java, weka

```
                        Cluster
Attribute                     0         1         2

C_AGE
  mean                   28.7493   36.4999   61.6494
  std. dev.               9.0175    4.3302    25.745

C_BIRTH_MONTH
  June                         9         1         1
  May                     4.9999    5.0001         1
  January                 4.9999         1    1.0001
  July                    3.5588         1    2.4412
  April                        1         1         5
  [total]                23.5587    9.0001   10.4412
```

This is the output I got from the Weka Java API, I wonder is it possible to obtain the value of the attribute from the clusters? eg: getting 28.7493 from cluster 0 in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that you are using the EM Clustering Algorithm here.

You could use the [EM.GetClusterModelsNumericAtts()](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/clusterers/EM.html#getClusterModelsNumericAtts%28%29) function to obtain the mean and standard deviation information.

Hope this helps!